# PHP code for showing information depending on selected language?

Tags: php

How to put information depending on selected language?

My language code [common.php] is almost same as here: [How to write code for multilingual in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894271/how-to-write-code-for-multilingual-in-php)

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

    if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
    {
        $lang = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $_GET['lang']);

    // register the session and set the cookie
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

        setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    }
    else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
    {
        $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    }
    else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
    {
        $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    }
    else
    {
        $lang = 'en';
    }

    switch ($lang) {
        case 'en':
            $lang_file = 'en.php';
            break;

        case 'de':
            $lang_file = 'de.php';
            break;

        case 'ru':
            $lang_file = 'ru.php';
            break;

        case 'chi':
            $lang_file = 'chi.php';
            break;

        case 'arm':
            $lang_file = 'arm.php';
            break;

        default:
            $lang_file = 'en.php';

    }

    include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
    ?>
```

I am using this code for choose  which information must be shown depending on user selected language:

```
<?php 
  function getLang()
{
return $_GET['lang'];
}
//which file will be used
if (getLang() == 'en') {
    include("e.php");
}
else if (getLang() == 'de') {
    include("d.php");
}
?>
```

It works great if I open my site with adding "localhost/**?lang=en**" or "localhost/**?lang=de**".
.  But when I'm just  open Localhost/
it gives an error (twice)

```
Notice: Undefined index: lang
```

I'm also tried this code for choosing the file, this code just shows nothing on index.php without adding "/?lang=XX"

```
<?php
if (@$_GET['lang'] == 'en') include('e.php');
?>
<?php
if (@$_GET['lang'] == 'de') include('d.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without adding `/?lang=XX` you are not passing any argument, and that means

you are not  assigning any value to the parameter `lang` (that's why you get the notice `Notice: Undefined index: lang`) 
so when you try to  `$_GET['lang']` the value will be null.

Use `isSet()` to check if a variable has been set a value.

So if you want the default language (the language for `localhost` without `/?lang=XX`) to be english, add in this line:

```
if (!isSet($_GET['lang'])){ $lang = 'en'; }
```

Comment: thanks for your advice, but @ Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: @Stz Oh my bad. I accidentally put the semi-colon `;` behind `}`. I've just corrected it. It should work now.

Comment: Now it not gives an error, but I m not sure where to put this row?

and does it Ok that we already have very similar rows in Common.php?


if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
    {
... ... ...
     else
        {
            $lang = 'en';
        }

or this is different?
sry I'm new in this..

Comment: @Stz Which codes above you are using? Are you using `<?php
    session_start();
    header('Cache-control: private');....` or  `<?php 
  function getLang()
{
return $_GET['lang'];
}....` or `<?php
if (@$_GET['lang'] == 'en') include('e.php')...`? If you are using the 2nd or 3rd one you need to add that line. If you are using the 1st one (the `Common.php`), everything will work well and you won't receive the notice `Notice: Undefined index: lang)`.

Comment: **<?php session_start(); header('Cache-control: private');....** this one is in Common.php   and   **<?php function getLang() { return $_GET['lang']; }....** this in index.php where I need to put different files depends on language

Comment: Then `if (!isSet($_GET['lang'])){ $lang = 'en'; }` is for your index.php. Regarding where to add this line, you will need to figure that out yourself. And you may have to modify it a bit to fit your needs. I suggest you to read more on [PHP](http://php.net/) (at least understand what arguments and parameters are) before coding in it. Or else you will keep encountering problems and errors.

Comment: Ok. Honestly..problem isn't solved. But I can't waste your time anymore.  It seems that my site doesn't want to make lang ='en' as default... or my code can't pull this info from cookies ... donno.... Thanks a Lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try below , now sure working or not..put in commom.php

```
$lang = (!empty($_GET['lang'])) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en';
```

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help, but I m not sure where exactly to put this row. tried two ways but not working